# Firebase JobDispatcher: Job scheduled for every hour executed more frequently

Tags: android, firebase, background, kotlin, job-scheduling

I have a task that should send location every hour to the server. However Job is executed more frequently (every 5-10 muntes).
Here is my job definition:

```
fun createJob(firebaseJobDispatcher: FirebaseJobDispatcher): Job? {
    logd(TAG, "create job ")
    val windowStart = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(50).toInt()
    return firebaseJobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setService(LocationJobService::class.java)
            .setTag("LocationJobService")
            .setReplaceCurrent(false)
            .setRecurring(true)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(windowStart, windowStart +TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(10).toInt()))
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
            .build()}
```

The Job service looks like this:

```
class LocationJobService : JobService() {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "LocationJobService"
    }
   override fun onStopJob(job: JobParameters): Boolean = true

    override fun onStartJob(job: JobParameters): Boolean {
        logd(TAG, "Job started")
            Thread({
                    LocationManager.updateAndSendLocationIfPossible()
                    jobFinished(job, true)
            }).start()

         return true
    }
}
```

Manifest definition:

```
<service
            android:exported="false"
            android:name=".services.LocationJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
            </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

Job scheduled onCreate of the application class.

The log of execution:

```
04-20 18:24:10.256 11796-11796/ D/LocationJobService: Job started
04-20 18:28:25.264 11796-11796/ D/LocationJobService: Job started
04-20 18:31:26.873 11796-11796/ D/LocationJobService: Job started
04-20 18:34:20.639 11796-11796/ D/LocationJobService: Job started
04-20 18:43:12.631 11796-11796/ D/LocationJobService: Job started
```

### Solution

Base [on this](https://medium.com/@akhilgupta.me/android-jobschedulers-cheat-sheet-971049c939d3) article I found my mistake. I passed **true** as the second parameter to *jobFinished(job,**true**)* and this means that my Job failed and must be retried based on a retry strategy, as soon as possible. I have changed it to **false** and this fixed my issue.

Comment: where you starting the job?

Comment: on Create of application class

Comment: everything seems fine. are you sure that previous job for debugging purposes with smaller interval not running?

Comment: At first, I used setReplaceCurrent as true, and had the same result. but after the application was restarted by the system, it reset the job and Job stopped to execute so I changed it to false

Comment: Try to reinstall app

Comment: Restarting application will not trigger job canceling. Even updating app version from google ply won’t do that

Comment: So how do I update o remove job?

Comment: Try to delete app and install new

Comment: Base on [this article](https://medium.com/@akhilgupta.me/android-jobschedulers-cheat-sheet-971049c939d3) I found my mistake.

Comment: Base on [this article](https://medium.com/@akhilgupta.me/android-jobschedulers-cheat-sheet-971049c939d3) I found my mistake.
I passed **true** as the second parameter to   jobFinished(job, true) and this means that my Job failed and must be retried based on a retry strategy. as soon as possible, changed it to false and this fixed my issue